# WCF Service to WCF Service Communication

Tags: wcf

I am trying to create a number of WCF services. These services will expose certain public methods and require to consume each other (i.e. call WCF Service methods from another WCF Service)

Is there any good reference tutorial material that I can refer to for this?

Thanks all in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Consuming a web service in another web service is no different to consuming it in any other client. You create a proxy and make your call so all the general WCF documentation and tutorials will apply.

However, this is usually not a good practice - although sometimes is unavoidable in an SOA. Services must be consumed by clients and they should not call each other unless they have to.

There are a host of problems that can happen. First of all, a service has to wait for the result of a synchronous call from one or more services to return and your service thread will be locked until those calls are finished. If one call takes long, the other service will take long as well and you will have scalability issues.

Let the client call these services. If a call requires data from another service, get the client to make the call and get the data and then make the call again.

Comment: The issue you describe can be solved with the reentrant concurrency mode.

Comment: reentrant allows two way communication (and is bad bad bad - IMHO). Here client users service1 which in turn, uses service2.

Answer (score 0):

Like you need proxy for a service  consumption the similar way is a service, it can be consumed by some client-part application. If this client is itself a service, it makes no difference.
Regarding you question, a lot is depending on your ultimate design and the goals. There are reason why some tasks  are divided into smaller services, but no one should do this lightly by just looking at the technical pros and cons. It is all drilling down to needs and business requirements.

Separation of concerns (Component separation/domain space separation etc.) will play a big part as for the consideration.

Service as a whole, whether does it represent a services as whole in terms of features. A service must be delivering what it needs to deliver as a service, not just a sub functions.

For the point asked in the question -
For this you know how to consume it in some .NET code, otherwise you would not
be able to test it. So, you can do the same in the project of your service.
Scalability, having running small services independently would sometimes offer better scalability, but you must always start from the point of doing it as a complete service.